# Playing WAV file from Arduino Uno using Ethernet R3 Shield

Tags: arduino-uno, speaker

I'm trying to start a project where I have a 6 sec recording (wav file: 8 bit, 8 or 16 kHz, mono) on a micro-SD card and want to play it through my Arduino Uno on an 8 Ohm, 0.1 W speaker. I've looked at many different forums and threads for how to do this. One that continually comes up is [this link](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SimpleAudioPlayer), but this is for the Due and I can't figure out how to adapt for the Uno.

The important bit is I am using an Ethernet R3 shield which has a built in micro-SD card reader. Much of the code and tutorials I found use the TMRpcm library, setting the speaker pin to 9, the SDChipSelectPin to 4, with various wire connection geometries depending on which tutorial you read. I really need help trying to figure out how the wiring is supposed to go. I, honestly, do not understand what's going on and am hoping someone will take the time and can explain this pretty pedagogically. Currently, no matter what I try, I just hear high-pitched static or fast periodic noises.

Answer (score 1):

Your Arduino UNO won't play any wave file the way you're expecting. There's not enough processing power to do that.
In order to play audio using small MCUs such as AVR (or PIC for example) you must use the BTC algorithm. Please, check this out : http://www.radanpro.com/Radan2400/mikrokontroleri/How%20to%20make%20sound%20with%20a%20PIC%20chip.htm
and download the software which can convert your wave file into an array which can be then played by Arduino using a BTC algorithm. Schematics on how to place reistors and speakers to match impedance are provided and suggested on the software as well.

Comment: Thank you ShunShirou. I'll try out your advice and repost to let you know how it goe